# Writing a Django CMS plugin & controlling admin options

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms

I've got a django cms gallery plugin which uses two models, `GalleryPlugin` and `Image`.

When I add the plugin to a `placeholder` the options in the `GalleryPlugin` frame display three instances of the `Image` model.

What controls how many times this displays? I only want a single instance of the `Image` model as there is a field within it to handle uploading of multiple images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMSPlugin is a subclass of ModelAdmin from django. have a look at django.contrib.admin documentation on how to limit the number of inline elements.

Comment: It's always the simple things that I overlook - thanks!